# Why can't I boot TAILS without a writable drive installed? Is it possible to do so?

Tags: tails

I use Tor through Tails, which I am running from a DVD.

It works fine with the hard drive in place, and works fine with the hard drive removed but a USB memory stick in one of the other USB ports, but it crashes when booting up if there is no writeable drive connected. Clearly it needs to write something, which I guess explains why it has to delete when I close down.

Is it possible to work around this? It seems obvious that if there is no writeable media at all, there is no risk.

Update.... have tried it with the latest version of Tails.  Does not work.  Perhaps something to do with the hardware?   It works fine from a USB.  Its a mystery.

Of course it is on-topic!  And it is reproducable by anyone who has the same equipment.  Sorry but using a VM doesnt cut it.

Finding what the problem is might reveale a security issue, who knows.

---

<sub><sup>Lenovo x61 with USB DVD player without hard drive; TAILS downloaded and installed via [tails.boum.org](https://tails.boum.org/) following their instructions. I have submitted a bug report.</sup></sub>

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your hardware, installation method, etc?  Check out these links below, and if nothing applies, consider filing a bug report there?
https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/bug_reporting/tails_does_not_start/index.en.html
https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/index.en.html

Comment: I don't think this is intentional: you should probably file a ticket with the tails devs, or ask them about it on IRC.

Comment: Try the [latest version](https://tails.boum.org/news/version_0.22/) and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Just tested this in a VM without harddisks. Both 0.21 and 0.22 boot up and function properly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not reproducible and so provides not value for other visitors,